# blender game engine objects ramdom duplicate

Tags: mesh, game-engine

I have a large landscape which has mountains . How can I spread my trees ramdomly into the landscape in a quick way instead of placing them one by one?  . Just to be specific , my land scape is made of cubes and looks similiar to minecraft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll likely want to use a particle system. Add a particle system to your mountain mesh, set it to hair, and set it to render your particles as your tree mesh. See the example below.

[image: example]

Comment: This may be better to explain in multiple steps instead of one image. Currently you can't see the settings where you would set the custom object for the particles.

Comment: @RayMairlot all the settings required to get the effect OP wants are here. If they want to change the other settings they can. EDIT: Nevermind, I'll update the image, I see what you mean